# Access one of several subcategories in Shopware Article view

Tags: smarty, shopware

I want to execute some code if an Article is assigned to a certain subcategory. The articles in the shop each have several categories and subcategories.

All this should happen in the template.

When typing *{$sArticle.categoryID}* I get one of the assigned category ID's, but not all of them, since it isn't an array.

I have used {debug} in the template to see if the targeted subcategory is present somewhere. It is not. Yet, in *s_articles_categories* the article is assigned to several categories, including the one I am looking for.

This is the basic structure of *s_articles_categories*:

```
id | articleID | categoryID
----------———————————————--
1  | 1         | 12
2  | 1         | 22
3  | 4         | 10
4  | 4         | 22
```

Basically I want something like this:

```
{foreach $ARTICLE.CATEGORY.ID as $ID}
    {if $ID == [NUMBER]}
        {SOME_OUTPUT}
        {BREAK}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

The example is using Pseudocode, since I am unsure how this actually should look like.

It goes through all the correlations in *s_articles_categories* and if it finds a match, does something.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Normally one would use the attribute fields to customize articles. Those attributes are available in every context the article is used.
When you want to do something on a category-base, you need to extend the detail view via php and add your variables on your own. This is not possible without using a plugin for it.

In short:

- subscribe to the detailpage event
- load the view and load your custom
- information via php/database add your new data to the view you can
- access it via template